# Difference between "mind" and "heart" in Gunslinger's Creed in Dark Tower

Tags: meaning

In the 2017 moive "Dark Tower" (based on Steven King's Dark Tower), the main character recites the Gunslinger's Creed which is as follows:

> "I do not aim with my hand; he who aims with his hand has forgotten the face of his father. I aim with my eye.
>
> I do not shoot with my hand; he who shoots with his hand has forgotten the face of his father. I shoot with my **mind**.
>
> I do not kill with my gun; he who kills with his gun has forgotten the face of his father. I kill with my **heart**."

I understand the difference between mind and heart is usually interpreted as the former being more rational and the latter being more sentimental. Do you think I can apply the same interpretation to this creed? That is, can I understand that "I shoot with my mind" suggests that you must shoot while being calm and having clear mind (not being absent-minded)? On the other hand, I interpreted "I kill with my heart" as not forgetting the purpose for fighting as a gunslinger, the savior of the world. These phrases are a bit poetic, so there may not be any clear-cut answer, but it would be helpful if someone could suggests some ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I don't know this creed so I can only work with the information in the question.*

The creed associates three progressive steps to the act of killing another being with different parts of the personal structure of the killer.

**to aim** using **sight** stresses that intention needs to come first and be narrowed down to focus on the target, eliminating any distraction. Not using the hand, but eyes, for this compares the focus required to the intentional limitation of the field of vision when aiming. Think of laser-sharp eyes starting at a target to express the extreme aim and intention to kill.

**to shoot** with the **mind** likens the act of setting the looking mechanism in motion to a rational process as a technical implementation of the intention of the first step. A "razor-sharp mind" is a frequent allegory of a (figurative) weapon.

but **to kill** with the **heart** states that ultimately the (physical or figurative) killing always is an emotional act. Only cutting the emotional bond with the victim actually removes the other person from the living.

So, the act of killing may be perceived to consist of or require technical or physical action - but only the emotional level actually executes and constitutes the killing of another being.